# Checking if First "Word" in Block of Text is a Time Using Regex in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to check whether the first word in a block of text is a time. If it exists the time will be in the format hh:mm.

I thought this word work but it is not recognising the times:

```
mystring = '17:23 Some text some text some text'
if mystring.split(' ', 1)[0] == '(\b[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\b)':
    print('x')
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Looks like you want to use regex, so `import re` and then `if re.search('(^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])', mystring): print('x')`

Comment: `==` checks for equality; it doesn't do regular-expression matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystring = '17:23 Some text some text some text'
if mystring.split(' ', 1)[0] == '(\b[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\b)':
    print('x')
```

You are doing literal string comparison here, you need to use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to get regular expression matching, in this case you might do
import re

```
import re
mystring = '17:23 Some text some text some text'
if re.match(r'[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\b', mystring):
    print('x')
```

Note that [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only check at begin of string (as opposed to `re.search`) so no prior processing is required. Note that I used so-called raw-string to make escaping easier - for further discussion see `re` module docs.